# PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code + Fabric

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, google-fabric

When I try to build my app it fails with above error.
what would I have to do ?
I appreciate any help :)

the scripts is

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the script from run scripts in build phases, then built my app, and re added my script.

cleaning project (ie. removing build folder from Xcode/DerivedData) has caused this error, I suppose.

Comment: Do you have more information about the error that you could share? Are you invoking the upload-symbols script directly or are you just trying to build your app with the run script build phase added?

Comment: For me had to put a new line after the script solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same issue today, by moving fabric DSYM upload to the new firebase distribution process, with run script.

It was interesting for me, that once it was successful, once not. The reason behind is that the new build system runs paralel, so when your script starts running, it is really not guaranteed that your file is already created what you want to work with.

To solve this, we should provide `"Input Files"` below the script to tell the building process, to wait to run this script until it s not there.

In this case we want to wait for the dsym file, so

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

should be added to the Input files area

So my full script looks like this

```
if [ ! -d ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME} ]; then
    echo "No such DSYM file"
    exit 1
fi

devDBValue="${GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS//*DEV_DATABASE=/}" 
devDBValue="${devDBValue// */}"

#Here I'm checking the type of database
if [ "$devDBValue" = "1" ];then
    echo "DB TYPE: DEV";
    "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyprojectName/GoogleService-Info-DEV.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
else
    echo "DB TYPE: PROD";
    "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyprojectName/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
fi
```